# Magento2 Something went wrong while saving the page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, cms-pages

I have problem with creating new page from backend
it shows me this message: Something went wrong while saving the page.

I can edit and save the page but I can't create the new page.
any idea??

Comment: Check logs on var/logs for any exceptions or more info related to this issue

Comment: Nothing in it related to cms page

Comment: Can you check console logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I got the solution for that:

I have installed MageWorx SeoBase extension that extension adds two fields in the cms_page table:
 1. meta_robots and
 2. mageworx_hreflang_identifier

but that field does not show on the content > page and both fields are set as nullable = false;

that's why the page was not saving I just go the database, open the cms_page table and just select true in a null field and now its working.

Answer (score 3):

The best idea to get the solution is try and catch which was introduced in PHP 5 then you only need to check exception message.

```
try{
  //Your code logic
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  //First find the message and then echo $e message.
  echo $e->getMessage(); die('errorMessage'); 
  $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the page.'));
}
```

Comment: Hi @manishgoswami can you please let me know I face below issue when creating a configurable product on version 2.1.0
------
exception 'Zend_Db_Select_Exception' with message 'You cannot define a correlation name 'oi' more than once'

Answer (score 1):

*Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Page\InlineEdit*

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $error = false;
    $messages = [];

    $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
    if (!($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax') && count($postItems))) {
        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => [__('Please correct the data sent.')],
            'error' => true,
        ]);
    }

    foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $pageId) {
        /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
        $page = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);
        try {
            /*Magento issue fix since it passes Invalid date for custom_theme_from*/
            $dataset = $postItems[$pageId];
            if(isset($dataset['custom_theme_from']) && $dataset['custom_theme_from']=="Invalid date"){
                unset($dataset['custom_theme_from']);
            }

            if(isset($dataset['custom_theme_to']) && $dataset['custom_theme_to']=="Invalid date"){
                unset($dataset['custom_theme_to']);
            }

            $postItems[$pageId] = $dataset;

            $pageData = $this->filterPost($postItems[$pageId]);
            $this->validatePost($pageData, $page, $error, $messages);
            $extendedPageData = $page->getData();
            $this->setCmsPageData($page, $extendedPageData, $pageData);
            $this->pageRepository->save($page);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithPageId($page, $e->getMessage());
            $error = true;
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithPageId($page, $e->getMessage());
            $error = true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $messages[] = $this->getErrorWithPageId(
                $page,
                __('Something went wrong while saving the page.')
            );
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => $messages,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
}
```